# MYSQL : Select count group by day with custom starting and ending hours for a day

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I like to group results by day,month year. My issue is that in my business, the day start at 2PM (14:00:00) and end at 8AM (8:00:00).

The goal here is counting number of unique customers who have registered during a day.

My table look like this:

```
id      customer    join_date               leave_date              duration
6247    4043035     2013-06-07 14:32:00     2013-06-07 14:57:24     1524
6248    4006087     2013-06-07 14:32:11     2013-06-07 14:41:18     547
6249    4020103     2013-06-07 14:32:30     2013-06-07 15:24:32     3122
6250    4020103     2013-06-07 14:32:30     2013-06-07 14:41:18     528
6251    4020103     2013-06-07 14:32:30     2013-06-07 15:55:33     4983
6252    4049611     2013-06-07 14:34:14     2013-06-07 17:14:25     9611
6253    4049611     2013-06-07 14:34:14     2013-06-07 14:57:15     1381
6254    4046774     2013-06-07 14:36:21     2013-06-07 14:41:18     297
6255    4048402     2013-06-07 14:37:51     2013-06-07 14:41:18     207
6256    4006073     2013-06-07 14:39:54     2013-06-07 14:42:19     145
6257    4022477     2013-06-07 14:40:40     2013-06-07 14:46:44     364
6258    4049923     2013-06-07 14:42:08     2013-06-07 14:57:09     901
6259    4018158     2013-06-07 14:45:05     2013-06-07 14:45:43     38
6260    4010012     2013-06-07 14:45:39     2013-06-07 14:46:44     65
6261    4018158     2013-06-07 14:45:43     2013-06-07 14:53:16     453
```

With "normal" days, my request look like this:

```
SELECT count(distinct l.customer) nbj,
       DAY(l.join_date) jour,
       MONTH(l.join_date) mois,
       str_to_date(l.join_date,'%Y-%m-%d') ordre
FROM log_waitingtime l
GROUP BY DAY(l.join_date), MONTH(l.join_date)
ORDER BY ordre ASC
```

It works fine.

I've try many things:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,202789,202807
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=819

I think those solution a complicated (I even don't understand everything.

Then, is there a more simple way to accomplish that in SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this query:

```
SELECT
  MONTH(l.join_date - INTERVAL 14 HOUR) mois,
  DAY(l.join_date - INTERVAL 14 HOUR) jour,
  COUNT(distinct l.customer) nbj,
  str_to_date(l.join_date - INTERVAL 14 HOUR,'%Y-%m-%d') ordre
FROM log_waitingtime l
GROUP BY
  MONTH(l.join_date - INTERVAL 14 HOUR),
  DAY(l.join_date - INTERVAL 14 HOUR)
ORDER BY
  ordre ASC
```

Comment: I've done another test with `where join_date >= '2013-06-12 14:00:00' and join_date <= '2013-06-13 8:00:00'` (Juste different day than the previous test). The result of the query is 386. Fthiella solution return 395. I think there is still an issue. I'll do further tests.

Comment: @Youpsla i'm shifting time back by 14 hours, so if join date is 2013-06-30 14:00:00 it will be counted as 2013-06-30 00:00:00 and if join date is 2013-07-01 08:00:00 it will be counted as 2013-06-30 18:00:00, I hope this is what you are looking for. You might want to exclude join dates from 8AM to 2PM if they exist.

Comment: @dianuj I've understood why I had differents results. There are Customer in the table who have a join_date before 2PM (13:52:24) for example. I like to count those people. Then I think I can do the start of the day à 8AM and the end at the following day at 7:59:59. Then I think I can replace `INTERVAL 14 HOUR` by `INTERVAL 8 HOUR` ?

Comment: My precedent comment is for you. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will display the customers who have registered during a day between 
**2PM (14:00:00) 8AM (8:00:00)** duration

```
SELECT q.* FROM(  
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.customer) nbj,
     DATE_FORMAT(l.join_date,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY,
       DAY(l.join_date) jour,
       MONTH(l.join_date) mois,
       STR_TO_DATE(l.join_date,'%Y-%m-%d') ordre
FROM log_waitingtime l
GROUP BY DAY(l.join_date), MONTH(l.join_date)    
) q WHERE q.TIMEONLY >= '14:00:00' OR q.TIMEONLY <= '08:00:00' 
ORDER BY q.jour,q.mois, q.ordre ASC
```

Comment: I've directly done this query to test the both proposed solutions:`SELECT count(distinct player) FROM 'log_waitingtime'
where join_date >= '2013-06-12 14:00:00' and join_date <= '2013-06-13 8:00:00' and game_type = '4' and game_amount = '6'`. The result is 366. Only solution proposed by fthiella gives the good result. The dianuj solution returns 411. I'm not enough SQL skills to know and understand why dianuj one's failed. But THANKS to you two for your quick answer.

Comment: FULL COMMENT : I've directly done this query to test the both proposed solutions:`SELECT count(distinct player) FROM 'log_waitingtime'
where join_date >= '2013-06-12 14:00:00' and join_date <= '2013-06-13 8:00:00'`. (I've added a WHERE clause just after `FROM log_waitingtime l` in both solutions). The result is 366. Only solution proposed by fthiella gives the good result. The dianuj solution returns 411. I'm not enough SQL skills to know and understand why dianuj one's failed. But THANKS to you two for your quick answer.